# awk filter rows that only consist a single letter

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file (file1) that looks like this:

```
ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 2 AA 234 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ROW 3 AA 122 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
...
```

there are multiple rows that contain different numbers of X.
however, the result should not contains the rows which only consist of X, it should be:

```
ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
...
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `awk`, print the lines where last field has at least one character which is not `X`:

```
awk '$NF ~ /[^X]/' file

ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
```

---

Or with `grep`:

```
grep -v '[[:space:]]XX*$' file
```

Comment: In case the input file is tab delimited, you have to set the separator, `awk -F'\t' '$NF ~ /[^X]/' file`.

Comment: Note that for lines containing only whitespace, `$NF`, becomes `$0`, the full record, and `awk` will filter out empty lines, but not blank lines.

Comment: True, then we can use the existing grep or a negative expression. I feel that there are more cases/versions prior to this. For example, a line where the 5th field is missing and the 4th is `X`. Or the 5th field is empty and the 4th is a number, then a negative expression would filter it. Some small modification would be needed probably for any command for cases not included into the example.

Answer (score 6):

Using standard `sed` to delete all lines that contain a space followed by only `X` at the end:

```bsh
sed '/ X\{1,\}$/d' file
```

or,

```bsh
sed '/ XX*$/d' file
```

With a `sed` that understands extended regular expressions if given the `-E` option:

```bsh
sed -E '/ X+$/d' file
```

If the delimiter in the file is not space but tab, then use `[[:blank:]]` in place of the initial space in the expression.

For each of the `sed '/RE/d'` variations above (and below), the equivalent `grep` command would be `grep -v 'RE'`, e.g.

```bsh
grep -v ' X\{1,\}$' file
```

is equivalent to

```bsh
sed '/ X\{1,\}$/d' file
```

---

To remove lines that have only copies of *any* single character at the end:

```bsh
sed '/ \(.\)\1*$/d' file
```

This matches a space followed by some character and then zero or more of that specific character to the end of the line.  Matched lines are deleted.

Just playing with the same idea, the following would remove lines that contains only a repeated sequence (such as `ABCABC` or `ABABABAB`) at the end:

```bsh
sed '/ \(..*\)\1\1*$/d' file
```

Comment: Note that `sed /pattern/d` is the same as  `grep -v pattern`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was in `sed` mode. You're correct. I'll add that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Do you mean "the same" in the sense of just comparing general behavior and response ? or did you mean that in some deeper algorithmic way ?

Answer (score 3):

To check every field rather than only the last field, you can do:

```
awk -F'(^|[\t ]+)X+([\t ]+|$)' 'NF==1' infile
```

or explicitly check every fields using loop:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~/^X+$/)next };1' infile
```

Or using the sub() function and with the help of word-boundaries (GNU awk?):

```
awk '{ bkp=$0; if(! sub("\\<X+\\>", "")) print bkp }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F ' X+$' 'NF == 1' file
```

Split line on any space, followed by just `X` till the end. If there are just one record, then the last field is made by only `X`.

---

```
perl -alne 'print if $F[-1] =~ y/X/-/ != length $F[-1]' test
```

If the number of the transliteration on the last field is equal to length of the field then the last record is made, for whole, by `X`.

Comment: All fine, but wouldn't the 2nd solution although perfectly legit, be particularly costlier ?

Comment: Surprise !  Your  `awk` one liner costs 7.01ms  and the `perl` one 4.60ms, while @kusalananda's `sed` based solution costs: 5.57ms, averaged over 1000 replicated executions (using `date +"%s.%N"`, i.e. wall clock time).  Why is Perl so darn fast, even with a transliteration operation and a conditional test that I still think _should_ be rather costly ?

Comment: @Cbhihe, `perl` doesn't decode its input as text by default. You'll probably get different different results if you run them under `LC_ALL=C`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/\([^ ]* \)\{4\}X\+$/!p' input_file
ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.put unless .words[4] ~~ /^ X+ $/ ;'
```

Sample Input:

```
ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 2 AA 234 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ROW 3 AA 122 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
```

Sample Output:

```
ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
```

Above uses a conditional to out`put` the line unless the 5th column (whitespace-separated `words`) matches entirely `X` from beginning to end of the string, i.e. `/^ … $/`.

Note: 5th column is zero-index `.words[4]`. Also, because the match consists of a single character, there's no need to create a custom character class and the regex can simply be written as `/^ X+ $/`. However, if you want to remove lines where the 5th column contains a mixture of `X` and `x`, write the regex like so (create a custom character class with `<[ … ]>`):

```perl
raku -ne '.put unless .words[4] ~~ /^ <[Xx]>+ $/ ;'
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$NF !~ /^X+$/' filename
```

output

```
ROW 1 AA 120 APFGHKDESFNNJFHGRIHJASFGNSKDHFIXXXXXX
ROW 4 AA 89  WUAHGLIHGUNGBGDSYUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFGOAYGIGWEIWIGFUEGFHUIWGEFU
ROW 5 AA 186 XXWANFJHOUNGRIGNO
ROW 6 AA 156 WANLHRIOGRNINGIJOHONJPHHYGKHDY
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -P '(?:(?!X)\S)\S*$' file
```

- GNU grep compiled with PCRE mode
- This will select all those lines which have atleast one non-X, nonwhitespace character in the end of line.
- The `(?!X)\S` tempers the \S to be all nonwhitespaces minus 'X'
- After we've seen atleast one tempered \S which is not X,